# Table inside of TD is not adjusting height

Tags: html, css

Having an issue with table CSS where the height of a table nested inside of a TD is not adjusting it's height when a TD in the same TR has it's height overflow (and it must be able to do so).

I have a table layout that looks roughly like this, and there is a min-width property on the TDs:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="TableCellA">Customer Admin User Account</td>
<td>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Content A</td>
        <td>Content B</td>  
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

A visual example of what happens is here:

[image]

I want the borders on the TDs to adjust height when the height of TableCellA changes.   Any suggestions on how to achieve that accepted!

Comment: please reproduce the same using fiddle. It will be helpful.

Comment: Don't nest tables. Use flex

Comment: In the snippet of code above you aren't closing the first opening <tr> close this. I have done so in this JSfiddle but can you add in some of the styling so that I can help you https://jsfiddle.net/twgnexpb/

Comment: that's not the exact code, i just typed it out as "for instance".  in the code, it does close properly.   unfortunately, sharing all the css applicable is not very simple, so if it comes to that i'll have to do it when i have more time.